# can't navigate by Navigation action from viewpager fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a fragment named **ViewPagerFragment** which comes to the display when I select a menu in bottomNavigationView. It becomes the currentDestination of navHostFragment.

In the **viewPagerFragment** there is a **tablayout** and a **viewpager**.
among the fragments of viewpager there is a fragment called **BudgetAndSpentFragment** which has a action to **AddBudgetFragment**. I pass a value by safeargs from BudgetAndSpentFragment to AddBudgetFragment.when I try to navigate to AddBudgetFragment with following code in **BudgetAndSpentFragment**

```
var directions=BudgetAndSpentFragmentDirections.actionBudgetAndSpentFragmentToAddBudgetFragment()
            directions.budgetList=simpleGenericAdapterWithBinding.dataSource.toTypedArray()
            findNavController().navigate(directions)
```

the app crashes with this message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination
> com.example.hishab:id/action_budgetAndSpentFragment_to_addBudgetFragment
> cannot be found from the current destination
> Destination(com.example.hishab:id/viewPagerTabFragment)
> label=ViewPagerTabFragment
> class=com.example.hishab.fragments.ViewPagerTabFragment

it's because **ViewPagerFragment** is the currentDestination not **BudgetAndSpentFragment**. How can I navigate to **AddBudgetFragment** with a value in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Please share your `navigation.xml` file or graph.

But based on the error message and code snippet, there might be a missing action in your nav graph. It seems you are attempting to navigate from ViewPagerFragment to AddBudgetFragment when you should be making that call from BudgetAndSpentFragment.

So to fix this, either add the action in the ViewPagerFragment fragment block in your navigation graph, or make that navigate call from BudgetAndSpentFragment instead of ViewPagerFragment, if that's what you want.

Comment: I am making the navigate call from BudgetAndSpentFragment

Comment: You clearly aren't based on the error message, though. So until you share more of your code it's very difficult, if not impossible, to help...